# How to fix swing and util timer conflict?

Tags: java, swing

I had being working on a game assignment and never used the util class. Now I need to use File IO so I need to the Scanner from java.util. But now everytime I run the program, it says "error: reference to Timer is ambiguous, both class java.util.Timer in java.util and class javax.swing.Timer in javax.swing match
    Timer myTimer;   "

What should I do?

Comment: use `java.util.Time` or `javax.swing.Timer`, depends on which one you do use, and add it in code, like `new javax.swing.Timer()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably imported `java.util.*` as well as `javax.swing.*`. Both contain a `Timer` class, so the compiler does not know which one you want.

The simplest solution is to add an additional import for `javax.swing.Timer` at the end of your imports. Even better would be to remove one of the * imports and just import the individual classes you need from that package.

BTW, you probably should separate your loading code into a separate class in the first place.